# Possible wrong result from JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime, android-jodatime

I'm using `JodaTime` for Android ([link](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)) and I'm trying to calculate the `Period` between two dates.

One date is from server with `Europe/London` timezone and the other date is one I create like :

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
DateTime now = DateTime.now(dateTimeZone);
```

What I want is to get the `Period` between **now** and the date I get from the server.

I'm creating a new `Period` instance like this :

```
Period period = new Period(serverDateTime, now, PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime());
```

but the results I get every time have an offset of 2 hours.

If I print serverDateTime : `2017-02-04T14:30:00.000+02:00` 
and `now` : `2017-02-04T14:30:13.862Z`

and for those values I get a `period.getHours() == 2`.

What should I change? Both times seem correct but somewhere there's an error

Answer (score 0):

So I was creating the time from server (which I got as a String) like :

```
DateTime serverDateTime = new DateTime(Integer.valueOf(year), Integer.valueOf(month),
            Integer.valueOf(day), Integer.valueOf(hours), Integer.valueOf(minutes));
```

and all I have to do was to add the `timezone`, so the answer is :

```
DateTime serverDateTime = new DateTime(Integer.valueOf(year), Integer.valueOf(month),
            Integer.valueOf(day), Integer.valueOf(hours), Integer.valueOf(minutes), dateTimeZone);
```